# TouchableOpacity inside Flatlist and inside tab view trigger onPress while swiping tabs on android

Tags: react-native

I use tocuableOpacity inside flatlist witch is inside rn tab view. I tried with react-navigation top tabs, same everything. I tried with tocuableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler and then have issue with tabs swipe.

RN 0.64

Answer (score 1):

Using `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native-gesture-handler` solves the issue for me.

Ref: https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/1045#issuecomment-1010023838